# Simultaneous iteration over two sets in Makefile

Tags: loops, makefile, gnu-make

The following is a simple loop over two make variables,

```
a=1 2 3
b=5 6 7

test:
    @for x in $(a);\
    do \
            for y in $(b);\
            do\
                    echo $$x $$y; \
            done \
    done
```

which produces

```
1 5
1 6
1 7
2 5
2 6
...
```

etc. Instead, I would like to get only

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

A big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should keep in mind that this command is purely shell, not make's internal syntax, so it isn't truly portable.

You can do e.g.:

```
SHELL:=bash
all:
    a=(1 2 3); \
    b=(5 6 7); \
    for i in `seq 0 $$(($${#a[@]}-1))`; do \
        echo "$${a[$$i]} => $${b[$$i]}"; \
    done
```

However this is usually bad idea to do so. It is barely readable, and changing default shell make uses may have implications. You probably better just write separate script and pass your data to it via ordinary makefile command execution.

Comment: I essentially ended up with your suggestion: just writing a python script which is executed in the Makefile. Thanks (also to bobbogo!).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in plain *make*.
Here is a (recursive) function that will pair up corresponding parameters:

```
pairup = $(if $1$2,$(firstword $1):$(firstword $2) $(call pairup,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1),$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2)))
```

Use it in a makefile like this:

```
a := 1 2 3
b := a b c
$(error [$(call pairup,$a, $b)])
```

giving, in the shell:

```
$ make
Makefile:4: *** [1:a 2:b 3:c ].  Stop.
```